# Disable Persistence in Flask Routes

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest, flask

I'm having a weird problem with my Flask web application.

I'm building a REST API with Flask and the Google App Engine, I can get it all to work, par for a weird problem, that wherever I've looked, I've only found people that want to have what I want to disable.

Below is a sample piece to explain my problem:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="")

counter = 0

@app.route('/api/v1.0/', methods=["POST", "OPTIONS"])
def api_base():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    return counter
```

I'd expect the output from the above to always be 1, as the instance is not persisted, but at the moment, I keep getting an incremental number from any call I do, be it from different machines, or incognito, or anything. The only way to get back a counter = 1 is by restarting the server.

Is there a way in Flask to define which variables should be persisted, and which should be not?  I'd like session and DB instances to be persisted, but not everything since it is causing race conditions in some of the more complex data processing.

I'm using Flask v0.11.

Comment: The variable is only set once when the server starts if you want it to reset....simply make it a local variable and include it in the route's function

Comment: Nothing here is being persisted. This is just how scopes work in Python. Module-level variables stick around until the process stops. With your example, running your application in multiple threads would result in multiple counters going at once. I'm not sure why you need a global variable. It sounds like you don't want one. Function-level variables are only in scope during the function call.

Comment: The global variable was there for example purposes. What I have is the following: `def api_base(): return API().get_all_people()` then API().get_all_people() has something of the kind `people = People()` `people.add_person('Joe')` `return people.get_all()`.\n what is happening is that I do not have a self.people = [] in the init of People class, and what is happening is that user 1 gets one Joe, user 2 gets 2 returns of Joe.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Application Globals](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#application-globals) section of the API? Particularly concerning `flask.g` Also the [db connection tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/tutorial/dbcon/) suggests using `flask.g` for DB connections.